# Convert Json payload to java objects

Tags: java, json, jdeveloper

I need to implement below json payload to java object including JSONArray and JSONObject

I tried using below java code in order to implement the same

```java
DWYT_productOrderResponse CreateProductOrderResponse = new DWYT_productOrderResponse();
ResultHeader rslthdr = new ResultHeader();
JSONObject productOrder = new JSONObject();

JSONArray orderIt = new JSONArray();

JSONObject produt = new JSONObject();

// List<ProductCharacteristic> ProductChara = new ArrayList<ProductCharacteristic>();

Map ProductChara = new LinkedHashMap();
//Map orderItem = new LinkedHashMap(); 
// OrderIteam[] orderItem;


if (1 == 1) {


    String output = null;


    try {

        productOrder.put("externalId", CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getExternalId());
        productOrder.put("description", CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getDescription());


        ProductChara.put("name", "CustomerName");
        ProductChara.put("value", CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getCustomerName());

        ProductChara.put("name", "CustomerContactNumber");
        ProductChara.put("value", CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getCustomerContactNumber());

        ProductChara.put("name", "CRMAddress");
        ProductChara.put("value", CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getCRMAddress());

        ProductChara.put("name", "CustomerEmail");
        ProductChara.put("value", CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getCustomerEmail());

        ProductChara.put("name", "CustomerGovetID");
        ProductChara.put("value", CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getCustomerGovtID());

        ProductChara.put("name", "ODBNo");
        ProductChara.put("value", CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getODBNO());


        produt.put("productCharacteristic", ProductChara);


        produt.put("product", produt);

        orderIt.put(produt);


        productOrder.put("orderItem", orderIt);

        productOrder.put("productOrder", productOrder);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is the result of json payload of the above code

```
{  
"externalId":"CRM000000912",
"description":"Activation Request",
"orderItem":[  
    {  
        "productCharacteristic":{  
            "name":"CustomerName",
            "value":"xxxx",
            "name":"CustomerContactNumber",
            "value":"5600000232",
            "name":"CRMAddress",
            "value":"xxxxxxx",
            "name":"CustomerEmail",
            "value":"xxx@xx.xxx",
            "name":"CustomerGovetID",
            "value":"1223232323232322",
            "name":"ODBNo",
            "value":"RYH-736834-JKS"
        }
    }
]
```

}

here is the json payload that I want to parse

```
{
    "externalId": " 12345678",
    "orderItem": [{
            "product": {
                "productCharacteristic": [{
                        "name": "CustomerName",
                        "value": "someone"
                    }, {
                        "name": 
                                                   "CustomerContactNumber",
                        "value": "13524687502"
                    }, {
                        "name": "CRMAddress",
                        "value": "xxxxxx"
                    }, {
                        "name": "CustomerEmail ",
                        "value": "XXX"
                    }, {
                        "name": " CustomerGovet.ID",
                        "value": "XXX"
                    }, {
                        "name": " ODBNo.",
                        "value": "XXX"
                    } 
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any easy way or java code that can help me to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: now I got the expected json payload after adding some enhancement to my code

```
         try {

                productOrder.put("externalId", CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getExternalId());
                productOrder.put("description", CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getDescription());


                ProductChara.put("name","CustomerName");
                ProductChara.put("value",CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getCustomerName());
                ProductCharaArray.put(ProductChara);

                ProductChara.put("name","CustomerContactNumber");
                ProductChara.put("value",CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getCustomerContactNumber());
                ProductCharaArray.put(ProductChara);

                ProductChara.put("name","CRMAddress");
                ProductChara.put("value",CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getCRMAddress());
                ProductCharaArray.put(ProductChara);

                ProductChara.put("name","CustomerEmail");
                ProductChara.put("value",CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getCustomerEmail());
                ProductCharaArray.put(ProductChara);

                ProductChara.put("name","CustomerGovetID");
                ProductChara.put("value",CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getCustomerGovtID());
                ProductCharaArray.put(ProductChara);

                ProductChara.put("name","ODBNo");
                ProductChara.put("value",CreateOrderReq.getProductOrder().getOrderItem().getProduct().getProductCharacteristic().getODBNO());
                ProductCharaArray.put(ProductChara);

                produt.put("productCharacteristic",ProductCharaArray);


                orderItm.put("product",produt);

               orderItemArray.put(orderItm);


                productOrder.put("orderItem", orderItemArray);




                System.out.println(productOrder.toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```